# IBM Watson Assistant: Expressions on dialog node condition using array?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

For IBM Watson Assistant and a dialog node condition I want to check if the context variable **long_name_context_var** has one of the values *1,2,3,4,5*. The normal way would be

```
$long_name_context_var == 1 || $long_name_context_var == 2 || 
$long_name_context_var == 3 || $long_name_context_var == 4 || 
$long_name_context_var == 5
```

But it is visually too long. Thus, I want to shorten it.
I tried to use JSONArray.contains and Array literals as

```
[1,2,3,4,5].contains($long_name_context_var)
```

but failed.

Doesn't the node condition support array literals? Or would it give a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

The [conditions on a dialog node in IBM Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-condition-syntax) support [SpEL-based expressions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods). This includes the [**contains** function on JSON arrays](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-contains).

Have you enabled debugging in the **Try it** to see the value of the context variable? I assume your node works with the "visually too long" expression. Is the type of the context variable a string or a number? Try using

```
["1","2","3","4","5"].contains($long_name_context_var)
```

What definitely works is to assign the array to a context variable (in my test **testme** in the context editor in **Try it**) and then use the following expression:

```
$testme.contains("3")
```

Else you could try the [**indexOf** function](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-indexOf).

Comment: The type of the context can be number or string, if it's number I'll use literal like [1,2], and if it's string, I'll use like ["1", "2"]. I checked in **Try it**, the Runtime Error says

Condition [["1","2"].contains("1")] could not be parsed. Check the syntax of the expression. SpEL syntax error: Expression [["1","2"].contains("1")] at position 4: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'comma(,)' (and there are 2 more errors in the log)

Comment: I prefer not to use context because it's not intuitive, you have to go to the other node to check the value of the context. More importantly, there're several places need this kind of expressions with all different values, means I have to define many contexts, but the thing is when the APP that calling Watson Assistant API, it also sends context via the http request, so it's not network traffic efficient to define many context.

Comment: You can define the context once, e.g., in the Welcome node. You don't need to send the context back and forth, the API has related settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$long_name_context_var >= 1 || $long_name_context_var <= 5
```

Comment: the values might be any number.

Comment: @Jarod This is the fastest way. You can add any interval. I agree, it does not look nice as with arrays.